# Eclipse GEF Edtor

Tags: eclipse, rcp, eclipse-gef

I am working on Graphical Editor i.e (GEF Editor). Files having .graph extensions opens in Graphical Editor and on save action of editor it generates some xml and properties files. Now, my use-case is to achieve the same functionality to generate ".graph" related xml and properties files even if anyone edits ".graph" file using eclipse default text or xml editor. 
Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: Which framework or library you are using for generate

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ResourceChangeListener`

```
IResourceChangeListener listener =  new IResourceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void resourceChanged(IResourceChangeEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("Text changed");
    }   
};
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().addResourceChangeListener(listener);
```